# Jenkins pipeline to verify multpile file existence in when condition

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I need to verify multiple file existence in single when condition using  && operation. 
check for any file that ends with .doc along with final.txt and proceed further. 
Second fileexistence(final.txt) seems to be working fine seperately. Please suggest on this

```
        when {
            expression
            { 
               return (fileExists("""ls ${Path}/${version}/test/*.doc""")) && !(fileExists("""${Path}/${Version}/test2/final.txt"""))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use allOf and not

```
when {
     allOf {
        expression { 
            return fileExists("ls ${Path}/${version}/test/*.doc") 
        }
        not {
            expression {
                return fileExists("${Path}/${Version}/test2/final.txt")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how *.doc(if any files exists containing doc extension) existence will be checked inside when expression?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, since they were working separately this should be the correct syntax to && conditions.